# Django search function that calls other views return ValueError

Tags: django, python-3.x

I created a view function to capture all search queries and then treat each depending on the type of search. In first step, I tried to pass all queries to another view function to see if this approach works:

in main app urls.py

```py
from searchapp.views import search

urlpatterns += [
    path('search', search)
]
```

in views.py for searchapp

```py
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return other_view_function(request, query=request.GET.get('q'))
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('Search query is not provided.')
```

However, I get value error no matter I include q in the call or not:

```html
The view searchapp.views.search didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

It's probably an obvious syntax error that I can't see!

Comment: It is *not* a syntax error. Likely your `other_view_function` did not return a `HttpResponse` object.

Comment: The other one is working perfectly fine when called directly. It also return the same ValueError when I call the search without q parameter.

Comment: Show the `other_view_function`. That function returning `None` is the only way `search` can return `None`.

Comment: @MehdiZere: yes, but since we do not know how you implemented that function, we can not see if something "strange" happens give you pass a `query` parameter.

Comment: Thank you both! I changed the url pattern to include / at the end so it looks like path('search/', search) and now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even with no q passed, the method is still GET, so the if condition is always True.

I changed the view function in this way and now it's working just fine:

```py
def search(request):
    if len(request.GET.get('q', '')) > 0:
        return other_view_function(request, query=request.GET.get('q'))
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotFound('Search query is not provided.')
```

also added an / to the urls.py

```py
from searchapp.views import search

urlpatterns += [
    path('search/', search)
]
```